# My program outputs nothing at all and I am stuck on this, also it says that I need to update variable in the loop

Tags: nested, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

```
Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
   char choice = c.next().charAt(0);
   char c_choice = c.next().charAt(0);

    do { // start menu
        System.out.println("Welcome to Dripp!");
        System.out.println("Please choose from one of our signature creations or create your own!");
        System.out.println("1. Oreo Overload $6.99");
        System.out.println("2. Birthday Cake Remix $6.99");
        System.out.println("3. Chocolate Devotion $6.99");
        System.out.println("4. Strawberry Blonde $6.99");
        System.out.println("5. Founders Favorite $6.99");
        System.out.println("6. Create Your Own!");

    } while (choice < '1' | choice > '6');

    System.out.println();

    switch (choice) {
        case '1':
            System.out.println("Ingredients: Sweet Cream Ice Cream with Chocolate Chips, double the OREO® Cookies and Fudge");
```

I am writing a code for a restuarnt and where the user can select something then it nests into another switch but for some reason the code is blank when i run it.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the choice before the `do-while` loop. To fix your code change it to this:

```
Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Dripp!");
    System.out.println("Please choose from one of our signature creations or create your own!");
    System.out.println("1. Oreo Overload $6.99");
    System.out.println("2. Birthday Cake Remix $6.99");
    System.out.println("3. Chocolate Devotion $6.99");
    System.out.println("4. Strawberry Blonde $6.99");
    System.out.println("5. Founders Favorite $6.99");
    System.out.println("6. Create Your Own!");

    char choice = c.next().charAt(0);
} while (choice < '1' | choice > '6');
//yadayada
```

This takes an input after you output the choices.